# Where to find conda bin file?

Tags: pip, conda, jupyterhub

I when doing pip list I see that conda is already installed in the following direction `/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.9/site-packages` but when calling conda it sais `$conda: command not found` I know that I need to set the enviromental variable but I can not find the direction of the bin file of the already installed conda.

By the way I am using jupyterhub

I am understandind this right?

find conda bin direction

in the /opt/tljh/user/bin there is not an executable file for conda.

Answer (score 0):

apparently if you install conda using pip then you will not have a conda standalone application. means not bin file possible to find.

Solution: intall conda using isntaller form http://conda.io/miniconda.html